# Create and display label via code

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a label and display it to the user, but I can not.

I have tried to copy the code for any label in InitializeComponent() ...

*(I added a label to Form1 using the toolbox.)*

```
partial class Form1
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "label1";
    }
}
```

... and then to apply it to my label.

*(I removed the label I added earlier.)*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Label label;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label = new Label();

        label.AutoSize = true;
        label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        label.Name = "label";
        label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
        label.TabIndex = 0;
        label.Text = "Test";

        //label.Enabled = true;
        label.Visible = true;
        //label.Select();
        //label.Show();
    }
}
```

But it does not work.
How to do ?

Comment: You haven't added the label to a form or other parent that would allow it to be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot vital part, i.e. add label to the form's `ControlCollection`:

```
this.Controls.Add(label);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add te label to add it to the forms' list of controls.

So, in your `Form1()` function, add the follwoing after the label is created:

```cs
this.Controls.Add(label);
```